# Multibranch Jenkins Pipeline - Limit branches to build to 1

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

Is it possible to limit a Multibranch pipeline to only build one branch at a time?

I have a pipeline that has steps that checkout, build, test, and then deploy.  The deploy phase does some copying/executing of files on a specific machine that cannot be done in parallel with other branch jobs.

I have tried:

```
properties([disableConcurrentBuilds()])
```

But this only limits concurrency on a branch basis, so still multiple branches will be run in parallel.

Also, in regular non-pipeline Jenkins jobs, there is an option checkbox:

"Execute concurrent builds if necessary"

[image: Checkbox]

But this is also not available in the multibranch configuration.

Is there some other configuration to achieve this or is it by design?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the above situation I would use [lockable resources](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Lockable+Resources+Plugin).

You can execute all of the branches in parallel.However, only one branch will executes locked step at any given point of time.

```groovy
stage("locked stage") {
  lock("deploy") {

    //deploy steps/copy files here

  } // resource is unlocked.
}
```

Comment: Note you can also lock the entire build by including the lock in the options directive.`pipeline { options { lock resource: 'test-dbs' } stages {...} }`

Comment: How might one use this syntax to lock multiple agents used in the pipeline?